# Calendar Item Not Reflecting Regional Time Zone Setting

Tags: calendar, power-automate, timezone

I have a flow that creates an event on our Hub calendar when an event is created on an associated site's calendar. Both sites are set to Eastern Time in the regional settings. Events created on the associated site that have no specific start or end time (All Day Event box is checked) show up as starting at 7pm the previous day on the Hub calendar. All other events created on the associated site that are not All Day Events show up with an accurate time on the Hub Calendar. I have attempted to convert the time zone in the flow, but the results did not change.[image]

```
                        Calendar Item Not Reflecting Regional Time Zone Setting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[Convert time zone]** as shown in the screenshot below. It worked for me to retain outlook emails [Received Time] when emails are transferred to SharePoint Online library.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding, Matiur! Unfortunately, I have tried converting the time zone in several different ways and nothing has worked. I think it might be a bug, since I thought I had tested this before and didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS support, the Create Item connector doesn't populate the Start Time value and the End Time value in the classic calendar list in Power Automate even though the parameters are showed correctly in the Create Item connector. I have submitted this feedback to PowerAutomate User Voice and requested the fix the connector.